# How to download and play a specific part of a large video file using requests python

Tags: python, python-requests, download, chunks, http-content-range

I'm trying to download a specific scene of a large video file that is 3GB+ using python requests and I'm limited on data usage and don't want to download the whole 3GB file just to get the specific part of around 300MB.

The website supports Range requests and I've tried downloading the last scene by adding the range header to my GET request:

```
{"Range":"bytes=16872448-"}
```

The website returns a valid response with the header: `'Content-Range': 'bytes 16872448-20873418/20873419'` and could download the chunks.

But when I try playing back the downloaded content its doesn't open using multiple media players with no success.

Was surprised that I couldn't find an answered question on here but hope someone can help me and anyone else with this issue.

Full Code:

```
import requests

header = {"Range":"bytes=16872448-"}

with requests.get(url, headers=header, stream=True) as resp:
    with open("video-part.mp4", 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Maybe show us more code?

Comment: The main bit is the range header and the website accepts the header, everything else is just basic python GET requests code but sure I've add it.

Comment: Video files, like in a mp4 container, contain metadata describing the streams. I don't think a video player can guess reliably these information if the beginning of the file is missing.

Comment: @Philo I'm not really knowledgeable on what content is required to play the half video. If there's information in the beginning of the file, would it be possible to download a small chunk of the start of the file and merge it with the part I'm looking for?

Comment: @Philo because I've tried doing just that and VLC shows the full video timestrip but plays nothing/blank video with no audio from the beginning. It plays the start if I download a couple of chunks from the beginning only but doesn't work if I do the mentioned

Comment: You could try with a local file, cut parts of it (eg. with dd on Linux), and check these parts with a player.

But, i suspect that bytes picked from such a file are not valid as a clip of a video.

A more practical solution is to try with yt-dlp (https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), eg. with --download-sections "*10:15-inf",as per the doc.